# Harmonizing data spread over multiple rows with duplicate values for some keys

Tags: python, apache-spark, nested, primary-key, data-cleaning

I face data spread over multiple columns.

Some rows hold duplicate data for a key.
Some semantically similar data
Others new fresh data (sometimes only for different keys - however sometimes also for the same key)

What could be a great strategy to make this data accessible? I want to have one row for the key.

I am trying to work with data about companies. It is from ORBIS.
For one primary key multiple rows hold values that describe it.

In some cases it is about NACE codes and classifications in other cases (like this one outlined below) it is about ID numbers (tax and others).

What is a great way to harmonize the data (in a somewhat generic way)?

I have explored:

- collect_list(struct(for each non-grouping-key-column))
- array_compact(collect_set) (for-each-non-grouping-key-column)
- combining the first aggregation with a UDF that JSONifies the data and tries to match similar values. However, it is only keeping the first occurence of a key (and I sometimes need multiple).

You find the code below for an reproducible example

The structure looks like this in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame(
    [
  {
    "bv_d_id_number": "XX00000000000",
    "national_id_number": "XX00000000000",
    "national_id_label": "European VAT number",
    "national_id_type": "European VAT number",
    "trade_register_number": None,
    "vat_per_tax_number": None,
    "european_vat_number": None,
    "lei_legal_entity_identifier": None,
    "statistical_number": None,
    "other_company_id_number": None,
    "ip_identification_number": None,
    "ip_identification_label": None,
    "_13": None,
    "ticker_symbol": None,
    "isin_number": None
  },
  {
    "bv_d_id_number": "XX00000000000",
    "national_id_number": "00000000000",
    "national_id_label": "TIN",
    "national_id_type": "TIN",
    "trade_register_number": None,
    "vat_per_tax_number": None,
    "european_vat_number": None,
    "lei_legal_entity_identifier": None,
    "statistical_number": None,
    "other_company_id_number": None,
    "ip_identification_number": None,
    "ip_identification_label": None,
    "_13": None,
    "ticker_symbol": None,
    "isin_number": None
  },
  {
    "bv_d_id_number": "XX00000000000",
    "national_id_number": "AA0000000",
    "national_id_label": "CCIAA number",
    "national_id_type": "Trade register number",
    "trade_register_number": "AA0000000",
    "vat_per_tax_number": "00000000000",
    "european_vat_number": "XX00000000000",
    "lei_legal_entity_identifier": None,
    "statistical_number": None,
    "other_company_id_number": None,
    "ip_identification_number": None,
    "ip_identification_label": None,
    "_13": None,
    "ticker_symbol": None,
    "isin_number": None
  },
  {
    "bv_d_id_number": "XX00000000000",
    "national_id_number": "00000000000",
    "national_id_label": "Codice fiscale",
    "national_id_type": "VAT/Tax number",
    "trade_register_number": None,
    "vat_per_tax_number": "00000000000",
    "european_vat_number": None,
    "lei_legal_entity_identifier": None,
    "statistical_number": None,
    "other_company_id_number": None,
    "ip_identification_number": None,
    "ip_identification_label": None,
    "_13": None,
    "ticker_symbol": None,
    "isin_number": None
  },
  {
    "bv_d_id_number": "XX00000000000",
    "national_id_number": "00000000000",
    "national_id_label": "Partita IVA",
    "national_id_type": "VAT/Tax number",
    "trade_register_number": None,
    "vat_per_tax_number": None,
    "european_vat_number": None,
    "lei_legal_entity_identifier": None,
    "statistical_number": None,
    "other_company_id_number": None,
    "ip_identification_number": None,
    "ip_identification_label": None,
    "_13": None,
    "ticker_symbol": None,
    "isin_number": None
  }
]

)
```

The cleanup functions are below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("orbis").master("local[2]").getOrCreate()
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(dxx.fillna(-1).fillna('NULL'))


collect_as_struct_list(sdf, grouping_keys=["bv_d_id_number"], mode="context").show()

root
 |-- bv_d_id_number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_values: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- national_id_number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- national_id_label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- national_id_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- trade_register_number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- vat_per_tax_number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- european_vat_number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lei_legal_entity_identifier: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- statistical_number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- other_company_id_number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ip_identification_number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ip_identification_label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _13: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ticker_symbol: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- isin_number: string (nullable = true)


collect_as_struct_list(sdf, grouping_keys=["bv_d_id_number"], mode="individual_set").show()
 root
 |-- bv_d_id_number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- national_id_number: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- national_id_label: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- national_id_type: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- trade_register_number: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- vat_per_tax_number: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- european_vat_number: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- lei_legal_entity_identifier: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- statistical_number: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- other_company_id_number: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- ip_identification_number: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- ip_identification_label: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- _13: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: boolean (containsNull = false)
 |-- ticker_symbol: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- isin_number: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)


def collect_as_struct_list(
    df: DataFrame,
    grouping_keys: list,
    included_columns: list = None,
    struct_name: str = "column_values",
    mode="context",
) -> DataFrame:
    if not isinstance(grouping_keys, list):
        raise ValueError("grouping_keys must be a list of column names")
    if not all(key in df.columns for key in grouping_keys):
        raise ValueError("All keys in grouping_keys must be present in the DataFrame")
    if included_columns is None:
        included_columns = [
            col_name for col_name in df.columns if col_name not in grouping_keys
        ]
    elif not isinstance(included_columns, list) or not all(
        col_name in df.columns for col_name in included_columns
    ):
        raise ValueError(
            "included_columns must be a list of valid column names from the DataFrame"
        )

    if mode == "context":
        struct_cols = F.struct(*included_columns)
        aggregated_df = df.groupBy(*grouping_keys).agg(
            F.collect_list(struct_cols).alias(struct_name)
        )

    if mode == "individual_set":
        aggregations = [
            F.array_compact(F.collect_set(col)).alias(col) for col in included_columns
        ]
        aggregated_df = df.groupBy(*grouping_keys).agg(*aggregations)

    return aggregated_df

def harmonize_data(column_values):
    # Initialize a dictionary to store unique values for each key
    condensed_info = {}

    for row in column_values:
        # Convert each Row to a dictionary
        entry = row.asDict()

        for key, value in entry.items():
            if value:  # Check if the value is not None/Null
                if key in condensed_info:
                    # If the key already exists, append the value to the list if it's unique
                    if value not in condensed_info[key]:
                        condensed_info[key].append(value)
                else:
                    # Initialize a new list for this key
                    condensed_info[key] = [value]

    # Optionally: Convert lists with a single value back to just the value
    for key in condensed_info:
        if len(condensed_info[key]) == 1:
            condensed_info[key] = condensed_info[key][0]

    return json.dumps(condensed_info)

harmonize_udf = udf(harmonize_data, StringType())

dd = collect_as_struct_list(sdf, grouping_keys=["bv_d_id_number"], mode="context")
result_df = dd.withColumn("harmonized_info", harmonize_udf(dd["column_values"]))
```

The particular version of spark is 3.5

Comment: Maybe pivoting out non duplicate (unique) values could work?

Comment: In fact first unpivoting wide to long and then aggregating might be the best option

Answer (score 0):

UNPIVOTing with some additional logic seems to be the right way forward.